# How to recover original excel password

Tags: password-cracking

I know how to remove the password protection from an excel document, but I was wondering if there was a method to recover the original password. I have a document encrypted with a 64 character password and I've been searching for ways to recover it but have found none.

Answer (score 3):

I would recreate the content found [here](http://encase-forensic-blog.guidancesoftware.com/2015/07/password-recovery-can-be-practical.html) but there really is no need because it is formatted so nicely. Basically, because the password is stored *with* the document, you can find the password hash pretty easily in a hex editor. From there, you can simply brute force it.

Comment: I don't think the brute forcing will work as it was a randomly generated 64 character password so I doubt it would be discovered.

Comment: Brute forcing will work. It's all just a matter of how much effort and of course what encryption algo was used. I'm not particularlly familiar with which algo it is using. For instance, if you toss a 64 character password on a WEP network, that is still easy to break...

Comment: The link changed to this:
https://www.guidancesoftware.com/blog/digital-forensics/2015/07/01/password-recovery-can-be-practical